# not able to set spring active profile in tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

Tomcat8 is set to run as a service on ubuntu

I have deployed an application in tomcat8, I want the app to load(dev,local,prod)environment specific propety file
Which config file should I set -Dspring.profiles.active=\"prod\" value so the correct property file is read.

I tried in catalina.sh as JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=\"prod\""
and also in /etc/default/tomcat8

Comment: Remove the escaped quotes from the `-Dspring.profiles.active=\"prod\"` -> `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod` should do the thing, but you can also add it to CATALINA_OPTS as explained below https://stackoverflow.com/a/46083532/344477

Answer (score 2):

In setenv.sh

> CATALINA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=prod  ...a whole bunch of stuff might already be here"

Comment: I dont see setenv.sh file in /usr/share/tomcat8/bin folder. Should I create one ?